# Querying only the latest sticky post

Tags: php, sticky, wordpress

So I'm trying to pull only the latest sticky post from WordPress and only 1. I am using 'showpost=1' but for some reason if I have two posts tagged as sticky both show up?

```
            <h2>Breaking News</h2>
    <?php
                query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
                if (have_posts()) {
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    if ( is_sticky() ) : ?>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">
        <div class="img-holder">
            <?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail('sticky-hp-thumbnails');
} 
?>
            <?php if( get_field('sticky_sub_heading') ): ?>
            <div class="tag">
                <p>
                    <?php the_field('sticky_sub_heading'); ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">
        <h3><a href"<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h3>
        <?php if( get_field('sticky_date') ): ?>
        <p class="sticky-date">
            <?php the_field('sticky_date'); ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p>
            <?php the_field('sticky_summary'); ?>
        </p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="button">Read More</a> </div>
    <?php endif;
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Where am I going wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  posts_per_page instead of "showposts"

i.e.

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1' );
```

Source:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

**Updated:** Adding WP_QUERY code to fetch latest sticky post:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">

    <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>

</div>              


<?php 
        endwhile; 
        endif;  
         wp_reset_postdata();
          ?>
```

Comment: That did not work, i also edited my code above, i was missing the last couple of lines

Comment: What about going WP_Query route as that is simpler and effective and even faster query for situations like this? If you can get it done with Wp_Query will you choose that? I can help with that if coding is the issue.

Comment: Yea i'm open to anything really

Comment: Ok I update my answer with WP_QUERY version for similar data fetching. You may then adapt that as per your code with AFC fields etc.

Comment: I posted above code which I tested on my local host which fetches the latest sticky post. And shows its title and excerpt. You can adapt it for all your other data you need to show.

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver, thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to solve (workaround) your problem is to remove the while loop. This way you'll print only one.

Of course, this is sub-optimal since other pages may be fetched and unused; you could try using `posts_per_page=1` or `post_limits=1` to see if solve the issue.

Comment: I would rather not use the "workaround" method but its a good backup option. Thanks